# Android Studio does not find Jitpack dependency while it can be added manually

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, dependencies, jitpack

I'm trying to add [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore) dependency to my project via Android Studio.

So I added Jitpack project's build.gradle like:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven {
          url 'https://maven.google.com/'
          name 'Google'
      }
      maven {
          url 'https://jitpack.io'
          name 'Jitpack'
      }
  }
}
```

Then I went File -> Project Structure -> app -> Dependencies -> I clicked + -> I chosen Library dependency

[image: this is how it looked like]

Then I typed `LiquidCore` -> nothing.
Then I typed `LiquidPlayer` -> nothing again.

When I **manually** added this to app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  //other
  implementation 'com.github.LiquidPlayer:LiquidCore:0.5.1'
}
```

then it works. **Why it was not found for the first way?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem. I didn't find another libraries also by your first way. We have to add manually.